# How to call a function on model Collection laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

before i post this I've searched a lot for an answer but no result please forgive me my English not that good

i have Laravel app that contains :

User Model

```
public function Follow()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Page::class,"follows","user_id","page_id");
}
```

Page Model

```
public function Posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Post Model

```
public function Page()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Page::class);
}
```

In the homeController I've index method that should return the posts of the user's followed pages

```
$user->follow()->get();
```

this returned only the Pages collection, I couldn't get the Posts or access any 
I need to access the posts and their properties, also if possible i need to count the post's likes.

thank you very much.

Comment: Try eager loading, `$user->follow()->with('posts')->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer after trillion attempts

```
    public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::User();
    $posts = [];

    foreach ($user->follow as $key => $page) 
    {
        foreach ($page->posts as $k => $post)
        {
            array_push($posts, $post);
        }

    }
    //return $posts;
    return view('home', compact('posts'));
}
```

I'm not able to access the likes count yet but i'll try the `with('')` method
I'll Update for any further Info

Answer (score 0):

You're using the function `follow()` that returns a page!! Check your return statement

should be:

`public function Follow()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Follow::class,"follows","user_id","page_id");
}`

Comment: I don't have Follow model  `follows` is a pivot table uses `user_id` `page_id` many to many relation

Comment: I know but just take a look of what the function `follow()` in your user model returns!! It returns a Page that's why you get the Page collection

Comment: yes that true it returns pages, i need the posts of those pages only.

Comment: $user->follow()->posts()->get() Something like that? Not sure if I miss something in that though like: first()

Comment: no this doesn't work it tells me that no posts method i tried many time and many options no success